# Identity theorem for functions with values in a $\mathbb{C}$ algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Suppose that $A$ is a finite-dimensional commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, and one has two analytic functions $f,g: A\rightarrow A$. Then is it true that if $f$ and $g$ coincide $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{C}^N\cong A$, then they must be identical on all of $A$?

This came up when I was reading pages 151-152 of the book Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators, where the algebra $A$ is the (commutative) algebra of even forms on a manifold and it is claimed (top of page 152) that the $A$-analyticity of the functions $f = dp_t/dt$ and $g = -Hp_t$ means that to check their equality it is sufficient to prove that they coincide as functions on the reals. (Here $dp_t/dt$ and $-Hp_t$ are somewhat complicated polynomials of differential forms.)

This step also seems to appear at the top of page 158 of John Roe's book (available freely at http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/roeindex.pdf).

If this is indeed true (or if there is another reason for this "analytic continuation" step), any explanations or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what means "coincide on $\mathbb{R}$" if $F,G : \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Say they coincide on $\mathbb{R}\times{0}$.

Comment: what about $F(x,y) = 0$,$G(x,y) = y$ ?

Comment: Right...so that musn't be what is meant by "analytic continuation".

Comment: in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Several_complex_variables they mention the identity theorem as $F = G$ on an open $\subset \mathbb{C}^n$, they don't mention curves (in $ \mathbb{R}^{2n}$). But in some special cases, the identity on a curve is probably sufficient (?)

Comment: Yeah, it looks unlikely that equality on $\mathbb{R}$ would be useful. I guess that was wishful thinking on my part. Maybe to show the equality I could also try brute force differentiation of Taylor series and using nilpotency of forms. (This would at least work for showing that the relation $\frac{d}{dt} e^{at} = ae^{at}$ generalises to the case when $a$ is a form, independent of $t$. Maybe it'll work for the other terms too...)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, here is the relevant reference that answers this question, page 29 of Liviu Nicolaescu's excellent notes:

http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/ind-thm.pdf

It isn't as simple as the identity-type theorem I thought might exist, but applies to power series, in particular polynomials, and answers precisely the question that is needed to make sense of the "analytic continuation" in the heat symbol proof above.